# Set constraint for UIView that is inside UITableView

Tags: uitableview, uiview, autolayout, constraints

This is my view hierarchy:

[image]

I want to set height constraint for the View, but it doesn't allow me to set it in the storyboard, and when I set it programatically I got a runtime error (nil)

Comment: views inside a tableview in storyboard are prototype cells (or headers). The height is set by the tableviewdelegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through your case in one of my project, which I needed to embed a view in a static table view. Yes, what different here is that IT IS STATIC, and you can create as many sections as you want.

What I did is really simple, you just need to adjust the view as you wish, then uncheck the axis that you don't want it to be auto layout.

For example, I wanted my view to fit with 44 as its height, and didn't want it to scale bottom down way. So I configed it as the picture bellow.

[image: example]

Hope it helps.